# Are there consequences to #define this self?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, self, compile-time-constant

Long has Objective C annoyed me with its decision to use `self` instead of `this`. Now, I want to end that frustration by placing this code somewhere at or near the start of my program:

```
#define this self
```

I know this will compile, and likely will work as I expect. However, I can't help but think there are... unforeseen consequences to this. **Is this a safe thing to do, or are there problems that will arise outside the simple problem I'm trying to solve?**

Comment: I understand the desire, but I implore you not to do this if your code is read or maintained by others.

Comment: There are other languages that use `self` similar to Objective-C. You should be able to match the language's convention rather than changing it to what you are comfortable with.

Comment: @EricAmorde oh, I've not heard of those. Which do that?

Comment: The first that come to my mind are Python and Ruby, although in Python it is only a convention to name the variable `self`.

Comment: The question contains a factual component, which is: is "this" reserved in Objective-C?  The religion-free answer to that is no...one is free to define this as self.   Funny how much dust got kicked up here, IMO.  I wouldn't do it, but I don't imagine myself having any trouble reading otherwise well-written code that made this choice.

Comment: @danh thank you! That's the kind of answer I was looking for, rather than the workplace-centric ones others have provided

Answer (score 6):

The consequence will likely be that no-one else but you can read your code and will get confused by your own convention here.

Answer (score 2):

Another consequence is that, if imported into C++ or Objective-C++ code, it could break code that uses `this` by turning it into `self` which would then be an undefined variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what bad things will happen? Your answer popped up in the VLQ review, probably because of the length.